# How to replace NULL in the last row with the same column's value on which Lead() function is applied in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have applied lead() function on Sales Column and since lead() returns NULL for the last row for the Column following_year_sales , I want the value to be 1990776.95 instead of NULL , how to resolve this ?

[image]

I have used this query and Output is shown in the image .

```
SELECT 
 salesman_id,
 year, 
 sales,
 LEAD(sales) OVER (
 ORDER BY year
 ) following_year_sales
FROM 
 salesman_performance
WHERE
 salesman_id = 55;
```

Please help .

Comment: The question is clear, and "a_horse" has given you the answer. I wonder, though, **why** you want to do this. What is wrong with leaving `NULL` as is in the last row? Obviously, that is the right thing to report; otherwise, someone reading the report in the future may get the wrong impression that the value for 2018 was the same as for 2017. How are they supposed to understand that there was **no** value for 2018, and that the value for 2017 was used instead?

Comment: This was just a sample case , the actual task is something else and I wanted logic for that task , anyways I got the way out .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `lead()` with three parameters. The second would be the number of rows to look ahead and the third a default value that is used in case there is no such row. If you specify the column again as the default, it uses that row's value

```
LEAD(sales, 1, sales) OVER (ORDER BY year) following_year_sales
```